# How could I invoke a url and execute all html calls on the server side?

Tags: c#, html

I am writing an simple test application that needs to take a url as input, load the page on the backend (server side) and follow all requests on the page as a normal browser would so that I can inspect each of the requests for certain elements.

I am thinking of using the Fiddler core apis for capturing all of the requests made so that I can inspect them. I was starting to look into things like webkit.net or something to embed a browser like control, but am not really finding anything that I can use without loading a browser window.

So the question is: what should I use for making server side, browser like calls to a url?

I am using c#/.net so would prefer something that uses that, but am open to other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you really need to handle all like a browser without a browser window then this might be useful http://awesomium.com/